# How to configure job in queue waiting time in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

If a job is waiting in the queue for a certain amount of time, the job is canceled for some reasons in my Jenkins. I am not sure why. I expect there should be a timeout value configured for how long a job can wait in the queue. Is there any configuration for that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeout duration for a particular project by defining a global timeout variable and using it in your job.

Go to `Manage Jenkins > Configure System` and in `Global Properties` check `Environment Variables`, then add a variable (ex: EXEC_TIME_OUT) to it and assign the timeout amount.

Note: The time you add are in minutes. That means if the value is 60, it is 60 minutes.

[image]

Then go to your job's configuration page and check `Abort the build if it's stuck` under `Build Environment` section.

Select `Absolute` for `Time-out strategy` and add `EXEC_TIME_OUT` as the `Time-out minutes.`

[image]

This way you can modify the job time-out duration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that these variables are used to define the timeout for a job execution. I am looking for a timeout about the job waiting in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a separate scheduler to trigger the queued builds?  If so, you may have an absolute timeout which is causing the queued builds to disappear.

You can test this yourself by scheduling a build on job y from job x and seeing the build in the job y queue.  When you abort job x, of course, any downstream jobs abort, or in the case of queueing they would disappear from the queue.